# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (18912, 35)

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I'm constructing an encoder-decoder using a BLSTM to model word inflection generation.

I'm not sure why I am getting the titular error message at the `model.fit` step. I am passing in a matrix of integer-encoded word vectors, but I was under the impression that my input would be converted to three dimensions when passed through the Embedding layer.

```
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(enc_len,))
encoder_embedding = Embedding(vocab_size, 100, mask_zero=True)(encoder_inputs)
encoder_outputs = Bidirectional(LSTM(100))(encoder_embedding)
e = Dense(200)(encoder_outputs)
e = RepeatVector(35)(e)

decoder_inputs_lemm = Input(shape=(dec_len,))
decoder_inputs_infl = Input(shape=(dec_len,))
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, 100) # shared weights

decoder_embedding_lemm = embedding_layer(decoder_inputs_lemm)
decoder_embedding_infl = embedding_layer(decoder_inputs_infl)
concat = Concatenate()([decoder_embedding_lemm, decoder_embedding_infl, e])

decoder_outputs = LSTM(100, return_sequences=True)(concat)
decoder_outputs = TimeDistributed(Dense(dec_len, activation='softmax'))(decoder_outputs)

# prepare input data
enc_lemma = pad_sequences([x[0] for x in data['train']], enc_len, padding='pre')
dec_lemma = pad_sequences([x[0] for x in data['train']], dec_len, padding='post')

dec_infl_shifted = pad_sequences([x[1] for x in data['train']], enc_len, padding='post')
dec_infl_shifted = np.hstack((np.full((dec_infl_shifted.shape[0], 1), 2), dec_infl_shifted))

dec_infl_target = pad_sequences([x[1] for x in data['train']], enc_len, padding='post')  # not shifted
dec_infl_target = np.hstack((dec_infl_target, np.full((dec_infl_target.shape[0], 1), 0)))

model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs_lemm, decoder_inputs_infl], decoder_outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit([enc_lemma, dec_lemma, dec_infl_shifted], dec_infl_target, epochs=30, verbose=1)
```

Here is the summary:

```
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 34)           0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)         (None, 34, 100)      6300        input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_1 (Bidirectional) (None, 200)          160800      embedding_1[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            (None, 35)           0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_3 (InputLayer)            (None, 35)           0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 200)          40200       bidirectional_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_2 (Embedding)         (None, 35, 100)      6300        input_2[0][0]                    
                                                                 input_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
repeat_vector_1 (RepeatVector)  (None, 35, 200)      0           dense_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 35, 400)      0           embedding_2[0][0]                
                                                                 embedding_2[1][0]                
                                                                 repeat_vector_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                   (None, 35, 100)      200400      concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_1 (TimeDistrib (None, 35, 35)       3535        lstm_2[0][0]                     
==================================================================================================
Total params: 417,535
Trainable params: 417,535
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
```

Comment: only a trial... if u set return_sequences=False in the last LSTM cell and u use simply a Dense layer without TimeDistributed, does it works?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani Thank you!! Yes, it does train if I do that, but I specifically need these for the task (my instructor explictly told me to use them).